# Caja flexbox al centro InternetExplorer (11)

Tags: css3, internet-explorer, flexbox

Intento alinear una caja en la que uso FlexBox y la tengo bien alineada en todos los navegadores en los que he probado (Chrome - Firefox - Opera).

Pero en internet explorer 11 (edge sin problemas) me alinea la caja a la derecha, como si no reconociese el tamaño o el margen.

Tengo el siguiente código HTML

```css
    .intro-foto{
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      min-height: 500px;
      margin:0 auto 90px auto;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
      background-attachment: scroll;
      display:flex;
        display:-webkit-flex;
        display:-moz-flex;
        display:-ms-flexbox;
        display:-o-flex;
      justify-content: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -moz-justify-content: center;
        -ms-justify-content: center;
        -o-justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -moz-align-items: center;
        -ms-align-items: center;
        -o-align-items: center;
    }
    .intro-texto{
      width:100%;
      flex:0 1 100%;
        -webkit-flex:0 1 100%;
        -moz-flex:0 1 100%;
        -ms-flex:0 1 100%;
        -o-flex:0 1 100%;
      margin:0 auto;
      max-width: 600px;
    }
```

```html
<section class="intro-foto">
  <article class="intro-texto">
    <h2 class="titulo-intro">Bienvenidos a nuestra web</h2>
    <div class="separator-intro"></div>
    <div class="texto-intro"><p>Lore ipsum et dolor...</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

He hecho varios intentos y quitando el max-width me lo mueve al centro pero con esa propiedad nada, me lo mueve a la derecha sin tener antes ningún tipo de bloque ni nada.

Answer (score 0):

No le veo mucho sentido pero quitando el valor `justify-content: center` parece ir bien en todos los navegadores.

```css
.intro-foto{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin:0 auto 90px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
  background-attachment: scroll;
  display:flex;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-moz-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:-o-flex;
  //justify-content: center;
    //-webkit-justify-content: center;
    //-moz-justify-content: center;
    //-ms-justify-content: center;
    //-o-justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    -o-align-items: center;
}
.intro-texto{
  border: solid 1px black;
  width:100%;
  flex:0 1 100%;
    -webkit-flex:0 1 100%;
    -moz-flex:0 1 100%;
    -ms-flex:0 1 100%;
    -o-flex:0 1 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro-foto">
        <article class="intro-texto">
          <h2 class="titulo-intro">Bienvenidos a nuestra web</h2>
          <div class="separator-intro"></div>
          <div class="texto-intro"><p>Lore ipsum et dolor...</p>
</div>
        </article>
      </section>
```

Comment: Es que es curioso...si quito el `max-width` y le pongo `width:600px` funciona, ahora como le ponga el `max-width` me falla. Igual que el alinear verticalmente...

Comment: @Marcos con el código que habeis puesto los dos en chrome aparece alineado verticalmente en el centro pero a la izquierda y en ie me aparece arriba y a la izquierda.

Answer (score 0):

En navegadores que no soporten flexbox puedes hacer esto:

1 - poner el padre en `position:relative`

2 - poner el hijo en `position:absolute`

3 - usar en el hijo

```
 top:50%;
 transform:translate(0%,-50%);
```

```css
.intro-foto{
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      min-height: 500px;
      margin:0 auto 90px auto;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
      background-attachment: scroll;
      position:relative;
    }
    .intro-texto{
      width:100%;
      margin:0 auto;
      max-width: 600px;
      top:50%;
      position:absolute;
      transform:translate(0%,-50%);
    }
```

```html
<section class="intro-foto">
  <article class="intro-texto">
    <h2 class="titulo-intro">Bienvenidos a nuestra web</h2>
    <div class="separator-intro"></div>
    <div class="texto-intro"><p>Lore ipsum et dolor...</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```